# Нужно вывести элемент json по заданному id

Tags: android

Добрый день,
мне нужно вывести элемент по введенному пользователем id. Мне нужно что-то поменять в запросе или методе onResponse()?

Запрос:

```
public interface RequestInterface {

    @GET("/posts/{n}")
    Call <List<Post>> getData(@Query("n") int n);
}
```

Ответ:

```
requestInterface.getData(3).enqueue(new Callback<List<Post>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, Response<List<Post>> response) {
                posts.addAll(response.body());

                recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

Post.java:

```
public class Post {
    @SerializedName("userId")
    @Expose
    private int userId;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("body")
    @Expose
    private String body;


    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }


    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}


public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}


public String getBody() {
    return body;
}


public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном виде `@GET("/posts/{n}")` - `n` это часть пути, поэтому в параметрах для него нужна аннотация `@Path`.

Аннотация же `@Query` используется для параметров запроса, которые в url будут выглядеть примерно так: `http://example.com/posts?n=3`.

То есть вам нужно заменить либо одно, либо другое, в зависимости от того, что ожидает сервер.

Comment: eugeneek, спасибо, а как сделать запросом вывод первых 5 элементов?

Comment: Всё зависит от того, как написан сервер. Нужно описание API. Возможно даже такого запроса вообще нет